# Why does this simple assignment to a multidimensional vba array raise a syntax error

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to assign two integers, "1" and "2" to a two-dimensional array of integers in VBA for Excel:

```
Dim arrPeople(4, 4) As Integer
arrPeople(0,0) = 1,2
```

The line where I am attempting to save the integer 1 to the first dimension of the array and the integer 2 to the second dimension of the first array item -- `arrPeople(0,0) = 1,2` -- raises a syntax error and I've not found an example that tells me why?

(I am not trying to insert "1,2", nor "1.2" using the European convention for a decimal point, nor any fractional number. Eventually, I would like to store an email address in one dimension of the array, and an article ID number from a webpage URL in the other dimension, but thought simplifying the problem to just storing integers would be helpful.)

Comment: Are you trying to use `1,2` as one-and-one-fifth or a one and a two?

Comment: I assume you're using the European convention of sing a comma as a radix (decimal) place marker. VBA uses `.` (dot) instead of a comma.

Comment: ^^ as Dai says but that won't work with an integer in any event.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to clarify what you're trying to do? As the above comments and the below answer indicate, it's quite hard to infer from what you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@elliotsvensson is correct: there is not a way to do what you want *with a 2-D array as a data structure*.  You may want a different data structure.  For example, a 1-D array of `Variant` can store another 1-D array in each slot, similar to the way C stores arrays:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Sub example()
    Dim arrPeople(4) As Variant
    arrPeople(0) = Array(1, 2)      ' Assign a whole row at once
    Debug.Print arrPeople(0)(0)     ' prints 1.  Note (0)(0) indexing rather than (0,0).
End Sub
```

As another example, for storing an email address and an article ID, you could use a `Collection` to map from one of those to the other.  You could use two `Collection`s for a bidirectional map.  Or, as you pointed out in your comment to elliot's answer, you could use two 1-D arrays.

Comment: Thank you, cxw and elliotsvensson. Perhaps my understanding of the purpose of a 2 dimensional array is incorrect. I will try to implement the array within a variant variable that you recommend, @cxw

Answer (score 2):

The two values "1,2" cannot be assigned to a single location in the array, such as `(0,0)`.  I suggest assigning 1 and 2 to their appropriate locations individually, as with:

```
arrPeople(0,0) = 1
arrPeople(1,0) = 2
```

Comment: Is there not a way to assign "1" to the first dimension and "2" to the second dimension of the first array item, which is what I'm trying to do? In other words, arrPeople(1,2)? If I use the alternative you've indicated I might as well use a single dimensional array. Thanks!